# Visual Studio Code reverted to an older version when it auto updated; complains about Windows 8/Windows 2012

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded  and installed Visual Studio Code version 1.87.2.  It did an automatic update and now is running version 1.79.2 (an older version).  It also now gives me a message when I start up

> Visual Studio Code on Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 will soon stop receiving updates.  Consider upgrading your windows version.

I am currently running Windows 11 not 8 or 2012. Is there something I have done or has VSCode lost it's mind? What version of VSCode should I be running and how do I get there?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here for us to assist--are you sure you're running a licensed version of Windows 11? Is this Win11 instance on a VM or is it installed on a physical computer? Have you rebooted yet or tried uninstalling VS Code completely and just installing the new version fresh? It _could_ simply be a bug in this specific build you updated to.

Comment: There are two different install types for vscode; user-level and system-level.  Perhaps you have both installed?

Comment: Windows 11 is licensed.  It is running on a laptop.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times.  I even manually deleted the misc folders that it created in %APPDATA% and my %USERPROFILE%/code after uninstalling and then reinstalled again.  Same results every time.

Comment: do you have anything under `C:\Program Files` or the x86 program files for Microsoft VS Code? how exactly did you download and install VS Code? from the official website? from the windows package manager? something else?

Comment: The installer for the 1.87.2 version (VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.87.2.exe) was downloaded from the VSCode website and it installed in my user/AppData/Local folder.  Since I used the same icon, I am assuming it installed its update in the same location.  I have blocked automatic updates so I am currently still sitting at 1.87.2.